# SQL update column with a concatenated value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create  a sql update statement which would make the current data below look like the desired data below.

Simply If the parent id is 0 then the ErrorDescriptionWithParent will be the errorDescrtiption of that row.

If the parent ID is not 0 then the errordescriptionwith parent will be the concatenated value of the error description of its parent seperated by the delimeter - and the childs error description.

please see the data below for an illustration. I tried to use the coalesce function but im able to create the appropriate string. thanks in advance

**Current Sample Data**

```
ID   ErrorDescription   ErrorDescriptionWithParent  ParentID
1    XYZ                                            0
2    Operator                                       1
```

**Desired Sample Data**

```
ID   ErrorDescription   ErrorDescriptionWithParent  ParentID
1    XYZ                XYZ                           0
2    Operator           XYZ-Operator                  1
```

The following is my update statement for the records with ParentID of 0.  I just need help in creating the update statemet to Update the ErrorDescriptionWithParent when ParentID is not 0. Thanks

```
    UPDATE errorcode
set ErrorDescriptionWithParent = ErrorDescription
where parentID = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
update e
set ErrorDescriptionWithParent = isnull(p.ErrorDescription + '-', '') + e.ErrorDescription
from errorcode e
  left join errorcode p on e.ParentID = e.ID
```

should work.